# Why does Pandas Plot looks different when using csv or xlsx data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

i've got two datasets with the exact same data but they look different when plotted the same way. One is a .xlsx file and one is a .csv file.

Here are the two codes:
For the CSV:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

daten = pd.read_csv(r"Path\Übungsdaten.csv", header=0, sep=";")


print("Total rows: {0}".format(len(daten)))
print(daten.columns)

plt.scatter(daten['InsuredValue'], daten['Policy'])
plt.xlim(2500000)
plt.ylim(100100)
plt.show()
```

And for the xlsx:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

daten = pd.read_excel(r"Path\Übungsdaten.xlsx")


print("Total rows: {0}".format(len(daten)))

plt.scatter(daten['InsuredValue'],daten['Policy'] )

plt.xlim(2500000)
plt.ylim(100100)
plt.show()
```

Here are the two Plots:

csv with `plt.xlim(2500000) plt.ylim(100100)`

[image: csvwithxlim]

and the csv without restrictions:

[image: csvwithoutrestricitons]

and finally the .xlsx plot:

[image]

My question is first of all, why is there a black bar on the bottom of the first two plots? (im guessing this is every single value of "InsuredValue") and how can I form the csv plo to the same ratio as the xlsx plot?

Thank you very much

Comment: Isn't the black line just overlapping values for the x-axis labels?
Did you make sure both the csv and xlsx imported values are the same?

Comment: The Black line is all the labels you're right. It commonly appears when the x-axis values are strings. Try check "InsuredValue" values type when you load csv and xlsx files.

Comment: This was the result of the type:
Policy           int64
InsuredValue    object

Comment: But when I look into the csv-File they are both standard-datatypes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to convert the "InsuredValue" column to int with the following code:

```
daten.astype({'InsuredValue':'int'})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).